# How to revert the intial decision for not saving username/password in OS X Firefox?

Tags: macos, firefox

A couple of times I clicked NO (or closed the pop-up) on Firefox suggestion to save username/password for a particular form.

How to revert this decision and force Firefox to ask again.

Comment: That is not possible without closing the tab and restarting it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you go to the Security tab of Firefox preferences, to the right of the checkbox labeled “Remember passwords for sites” there will be an “Exceptions…” button. This will show a dialog from which you can select and remove the websites you told Firefox to never save passwords for.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: that does not answer the question?

Comment: @Buscar웃 What do you mean?

Comment: how is that going to force FF to ask to save password while already logged in ??

Comment: I didn't see anything about already being logged in in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Websites remembering you and automatically logging you in is stored in a cookie.

Create an Allow cookie exception to keep such a cookie, especially for secure websites and if cookies expire when Firefox is closed.
To see all History and Cookie settings, choose:

Firefox > Preferences > Privacy > Firefox will: "Use custom settings for history"
Firefox > Preferences > Privacy > Cookies: Exceptions